# How to access predefined variables within cfscript?

Tags: coldfusion, mura

The following code works:

```
<cfoutput>#$.currentURL()#</cfoutput>
```

However, within a function, "$" is not available.

```
<cfscript>
function myTest() {
  return $.currentURL();
}
</cfscript>
```

Does anyone know what actually is the equivalent of $ within a function?

Likewise, `#pluginConfig.getDirectory()#` works when used directly in cfoutput. However, within a cfscript function, it reports "unknown variable pluginConfig."

Thank you for advance for guiding me in the right direction.

Comment: Your post suggests two possible problems, the function and the fact that you are using cfscript.  To narrow it down, either write a function with the cffunction and cfreturn tags, or, do a writedump of $.currentURL() within a cfscript block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing code outside the Mura Event Scope (like you do with that function), you have to obtain an instance of the Mura Scope ($) yourself. This can be done using the following code:

```
$ = application.serviceFactory.getBean('$');
```

Next you'll have to initialise the instance using an event object, a struct with value pairs or a 'siteID':

```
$.init(event);
$.init(myStruct);
$.init(siteID);
```

The same counts for the pluginConfig, this you can abtain via the Mura Scope. You'll have to pass the pluginID, moduleID, name or package of the plugin:

```
$.getPlugin(pluginID);
$.getPlugin(moduleID);
$.getPlugin(name);
$.getPlugin(package);
```

An other option you have is to pass the Mura Scope and the pluginConfig as arguments to the function. When writing a small plugin, this might be the easier way. But when writting medium or large plugins, it will get a bit messy when you're passing along these objects all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The $ is used as a special framework variable in some CF frameworks (like Mura). You will need to figure out the framework context (if any) your code is executing in